# how to export data to csv using python

Tags: python, csv

i have data `[4 4 4 ... 2 4 1]`

i use code like this..

```
file=open('cluster.csv','a')
tulis=csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
tulis.writerows([y_kmeans])
file.close()
```

the result my code is like this:

```
4,4,4,2,4,4,1,3,.......
```

I want the output to have no commas, and every comma moves to the next rows in csv, like this
[image: i]

please help me

Comment: Which application you are using to open the csv? Can you open the file in pain text editor and check first?  If it is stored as comma separated values (or any other separator) then double check the application settings that shows these values in new lines.

Comment: i'm using excel 2016... ya i open use other app and it is stored as comma separated values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the requirement completely. CSV means comma separated values. So comma is the default separator (delimiter) between variables. However you can change that. If you rather want to use a space as delimiter(separator) you will say the following.

```py
file=open('cluster.csv','a')
tulis=csv.writer(file,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\n')
tulis.writerows([y_kmeans])
file.close()
```

I however don't understand what you mean by " and every comma moves to the next rows in csv" in your question.